# Mounting an old amzon volume to a new instance because I got locked out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got locked out of my amazon instance. I read that I can create a new instance and attach that volume to the new instance. I attached the old volume to the new instance and the management console says its at /dev/sdf. My question is how do I access that volume ? I read that I can access it by mounting. I tried doing this

```
sudo mount /dev/sdf ~/vol1/
```

but I get the error

```
[root@ip-172-31-42-113 ~]# sudo mount /dev/sdf ~/vol1/
mount: wrong fstype, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Any suggestions on how I can access that volume ? I need to change the permissions of  `home/ec2-user` of that volume. Apparently I set it to 777 and because of the relaxed permission setting I think I got locked out of it ? Also can you tell me what the default permission for `home/ec2-user` should be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will most likely be a partition `/dev/sdf1` (notice the `1`) so you have to mount that:

```
~ $ sudo mount /dev/sdf1 ~/vol1
```

Then change what you need to change (e.g. add your new, working, ssh key to `~/vol1/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`) and unmount is again with:

```
~ $ sudo umount ~/vol1
```

Finally re-attach it to your old instance **as `/dev/sda1`** (or `/dev/xvda1`, depending on what it was before) - even if that device name is not offered in the drop-down list. Just type it in when attaching the volume.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes thank you. I am able to access it. Can you tell me what the default permission for `home/ec2-user` should be ? I accidentally changed it to 777 and I believe that was the reason I got locked out. I am not sure what the default for it was or what I should change it to ?

Comment: Create a new small instance to see a working example. Increase the `LogLevel` setting of sshd to check if it complains about there permissions on any home directories.

Comment: @MistyD change it to 700, that will do.